# Google App Engine: How do I put variables in my url in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to figure something out with the app.yaml file.

How do I get "nh" and "dover" out of my url: http://www.mysite.com/boats/nh/dover

I'm assuming would would do something like:

```
- url: /boats/<state>/<city>
  script: boats.py
```

and then be able to get the variables somehow but I've had a hard time finding documentation for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regular expression groups in app.yaml don't get passed to webapps directly. But if you're using the webapp framework, groups in *its* routing regular expressions do get passed to webapps. For example:

app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: boats.py
```

boats.py:

```
class BoatsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, state, city):
    # Do something with state and city. They're strings, not ints, remember!

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/boats/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', BoatsHandler),
])

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: @Nick: I have added comments to my answer: I just forgot to mention the setup of the webapp application with the regexes.

Comment: Solid answer nick, great guidance dldupont, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They mention some stuff here, but its kind of vague:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html

Answer (score 1):

```
- url: /boats/.*
  script: boats.py
```

and you retrieve the rest of the URL through the `request` [object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html).

```
class BoatsHandler( webapp.RequestHandler ):
  def get(self, url_fragment=None):
   #do something with url_fragment
```

Comment: Ok, cool, how would I go about getting those variables out of said request object? (in boats.py I assume)

Comment: This is incorrect - regexes in app.yaml are not passed to webapp apps.

Comment: It won't get the url fragment as an additional argument to the get function as you suggest in your code snippet.

Comment: Oh I see: I forgot to mention that the REGEXES must be setup when instantiating the webapp e.g. `application=webapp.WSGIApplication(URL_REGEXES)`

Comment: That's kind of vital - and even then, regex components only get passed to the RequestHandler subclass if they're parenthesized, in which case you can just split out the components he originally asked for - see my answer.